# Change time to 12 hr format

Tags: php

I need to add a time selector with 30 min intervals. I did a quick search and came across the following function that does a great job in  very efficient way:

```
for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) // the interval for mins is '30'
        echo '<option>'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'
                       .str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';
```

The only problem is that it outputs in the following format:

```
<option>11:00</option>
<option>11:30</option>
<option>12:00</option>
<option>12:30</option>
<option>13:00</option>
<option>13:30</option>
```

I need to make a few modifications. I'd like to keep the value in the same format, but display it in 12 hr format:

```
<option value="11:00">11:00 am</option>
<option value="11:30">11:30 am</option>
<option value="12:00">12:00 pm</option>
<option value="12:30">12:30 pm</option>
<option value="13:00">1:00 pm</option>
<option value="13:30">1:30 pm</option>
```

So, the first part is easy, but not really clear on the display side:

```
for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) // the interval for mins is '30'
        echo '<option value="'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'                           .str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'">'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'
                       .str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';
```

Comment: What should the `value` attribute look like? Something like `11:30am` and `11:30pm`?

Comment: On the page you got this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941202/how-to-create-a-dropdown-of-time try the code below the accepted answer with the DateTime object. That approach lets you customize the format using `$time->format('H:i:s')` or whatever you want the format to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) // the interval for mins is '30'
        echo '<option>'.str_pad(($hours%12),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'
                   .str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'</option>';
```

Although, there are other ways to do this. Check the remaining answers for more ideas. I think you are going to learn more from them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is using your current implementation, just altered a bit.

```
for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) { // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) { // the interval for mins is '30'

         $time =  str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).':'.str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);

         echo '<option value="'.date('h:i', strtotime($time)).'">'.date('h:i', strtotime($time)).'</option>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it complicated, use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
<?php

    $start = new DateTime("00:00");
    $end = (new DateTime("00:00"))->modify("+ 1 day");
    $interval = new DateInterval('PT30M');
    $period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    echo "<select>";
    foreach($period as $time)
        echo "<option value='" . $time->format("H:i") . "'>" . $time->format("h:i a") . "</option>";
    echo "</select>";

?>
```

Then you can change the format as you want it!

With 12 hour format (`h:i a`):

```
12:00 am
//...
11:30 pm
```

OR 24 hour format (`H:i`):

```
00:00
//...
23:30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$start    = new DateTime('2000-01-01 00:00');
$end      = new DateTime('2000-01-02 00:00');
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('+30 minutes');
$period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $time) {
    echo $time->format("H:ia") . "<br>\n";
}
```

It is a modified version of a [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019961/how-to-find-find-first-sunday-of-every-month#answer-14020329).

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) { // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=30) { // the interval for mins is '30'
        $hours = str_pad($hours, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $mins = str_pad($mins, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $twelve_hours = ($hours > 12) ? $hours - 12 : $hours;
        $am_pm = ($hours > 12) ? "pm" : "am";
        echo '<option value="'.$hours.":".$mins.'">'.$twelve_hours.":".$mins." ".$am_pm.'</option>';
    }
}
```

Simply subtract 12 from the hours if they are > 12, and set *am/pm* if they still are > 12

Result:

```
...
<option value="12:00">12:00 am</option>
<option value="12:30">12:30 am</option>
<option value="13:00">1:00 pm</option>
<option value="14:00">2:00 pm</option>
<option value="14:30">2:30 pm</option>
...
```