# How to show drop down time from 6am to 6am instead of 00:00 to 24:00?

Tags: php

currently I have a drop down menu that shows list of 24 hour format time starting from 00:00 to 23:55 in 5 mins interval.

However, i wish to show the time starting from 06:00 am to 06:00 am in the list. I have been trying to figure this out but not very sure how to achieve this. Can anyone help?

Below is my drop down code:

```
<label>End Time:</label>

    <select name="end_time" id="endtime" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
                <?php  
                    for ($x = 0; $x <= 23; $x++) {

                            if($x < 10){                
                                $h = '0'.$x;    
                            }else{
                                 $h = $x;
                                }

                                        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $h.":00"; ?>"><?php echo $h; ?>:00</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $h.":05"; ?>"><?php echo $h; ?>:05</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $h.":10"; ?>"><?php echo $h; ?>:10</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $h.":15"; ?>"><?php echo $h; ?>:15</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $h.":20"; ?>"><?php echo $h; ?>:20</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $h.":25"; ?>"><?php echo $h; ?>:25</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $h.":30"; ?>"><?php echo $h; ?>:30</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $h.":35"; ?>"><?php echo $h; ?>:35</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $h.":40"; ?>"><?php echo $h; ?>:40</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $h.":45"; ?>"><?php echo $h; ?>:45</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $h.":50"; ?>"><?php echo $h; ?>:50</option>
            <option value="<?php echo $h.":55"; ?>"><?php echo $h; ?>:55</option>
                                    <?php } ?>
                            </select>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a dropdown of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7941202/how-to-create-a-dropdown-of-time)

Comment: @SzántóZoltán I'm asking for drop down time to start from 06:00 to 05:55. This is not duplicate as the other post is talking about generating 00:00 to 24:00. Please read my question properly. Thanks

Comment: Probably easiest if you use two loops - one from 6am to midnight, and one from midnight to 6am again.

Comment: @04FS i have thought about that i prefer to keep my code less repetitive as possible

Comment: @ThaiThai if you look at the second answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38269436/2037755) that does exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out myself how get drop down menu start from 6am to 6am (next date) Below is my code:

```
<?php 
 $h = 0; 
for ($x = 6; $x <= 30; $x++) {

 if($x >= 6 && $x < 24){
  echo $x."<br/>";
 }

  if($x >= 24){
    echo $h."<br/>";
    $h += 1;
 }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the loop in a such way to shift 0 -> 6, 1 -> 7,.. 24 -> 0, 25 -> 1...

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) {
    $x = ($i + 6) % 24;
    if($x < 10) {                
        $h = '0'.$x;    
    } else {
         $h = $x;
    }
    echo $x."<br/>";
}
```